# Group androgynous names and sum amount for each year in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split-apply-combine

I have a data frame with 4 columns titled 'year' 'name' 'sex' 'amount'. Here is a sample data set

```
set.seed(1)
    data = data.frame(year=sample(1950:2000, 50, replace=TRUE),name=sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE),
                       sex=sample(c("M", "F"), 50, replace=TRUE), amount=sample(40:100, 50, replace=TRUE))
```

I want to find only names that occur as both an ‘m’ and an ‘f’ and sum the amount for each year.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Like `aggregate(amount ~ name + sex, data[data$year == 1950,], sum)`?  In this case it looks like there were no females for 1950.  Oh, well actually that can differ since you used `sample` Please use `set.seed` when using `sample` so that we can use the exact same data you are using

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear in my question – I want to return the sum of the androgynous names for each year, so that at a glance I can see the amount born with an androgynous name in a certain year.  Your code returns:

name sex amount
   R   F     69 

As R was the only name to appear in 1950 I am unsure if the code has worked or not. I tried aggregate(amount ~ name + sex, data[data$year,], sum) on my own data frame and it returns 3 columns ‘name’ ‘sex’ ‘amount’ but the ‘year’ column is missing and all the values in the ‘sex’ column are ‘f’?

Comment: We will continue to get mis-matched results until you add `set.seed(1)` to the top of your code in the post, and then create the `data` set again.  This is the consequence of using `sample`, like I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the data a bit, so that there would be common names in some years. On visual inspection this seems to work. The syntax may appear a bit cryptic if you are not familiar with `data.table` but it's concise and  should be quite efficient:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(year=sample(1950:1960, 100, replace=TRUE),name=sample(LETTERS, 100, replace=TRUE),
                  sex=sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace=TRUE), amount=sample(40:100, 100,  replace=TRUE))
setDT(data) ## change to data.table format
data[, common=sum(amount[name %in% intersect(name[sex=="M"], name[sex=="F"])]), by=year]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The code on the sample data returns two columns 'year' and 'v1' I presume v1 is the sum of the names that occur as both 'm' and 'f'? When I run it on my own data frame which is quite large it returns the first and the last 5 years. This is fine - will all the years appear though if I decide to plot the information as a graph ?

Comment: That is just the print method for `data.table`. The data is all there and you can use it as a normal `data.frame`, or you can convert it with `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: Just to be clear, this only adds occurrences of names that were common to both girls and boys *in that given year*. If a name is used for girls in one year, and boys in another, then it is not counted.