# Selecting & grouping dual-category data from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I really need help on how to approach a problem.  I have a data set that looks like this..

```
Name   Sex    Total    
Anna   F      10
Jamie  M      2
Jamie  F      7
Mike   M      13
Sam    F      6
Sam    M      3

structure(list(Name = c("Anna", "Jamie", "Jamie", "Mike", "Sam", "Sam"), 
Sex = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M"), Total = c(10L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 3L)), 
.Names = c("Name", "Sex", "Total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

What I want to do is get the names that are both male and female names, so the results will look like..

```
Name   Sex  Total
Jamie  M    2
Jamie  F    7
Sam    M    3
Sam    F    6
```

But I'm really stumped on how to approach it.

Comment: Similar, but a bit more involved task [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347343/group-androgynous-names-and-sum-amount-for-each-year-in-a-data-frame-in-r).

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would approach it assuming the data is stored in `d`:

```
# get a vector (set) of names that are use by both M and F
dual.names <- intersect(d$Name[d$Sex=='M'], d$Name[d$Sex=='F'])

# use set of dual names to filter data
d[d$Name %in% dual.names, ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory Hadleyverse (`dplyr` & `tidyr`) answer:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  spread(Sex, Total) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(M), !is.na(F)) %>% 
  gather(Sex, Total, M, F) %>%
  arrange(Name)

##    Name Sex Total
## 1 Jamie   M     2
## 2 Jamie   F     7
## 3   Sam   M     3
## 4   Sam   F     6
```

**EDIT** and **MUCH** better `dplyr` approach via @konvas' comment:

```
dat %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(length(unique(Sex)) == 2)
```

**EDIT** and, further refined by @David's comment:

```
dat %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(n_distinct(Sex) == 2)
```

(Can I transfer points to @konvas & @David? :-)

Comment: I think you can avoid spreading and gathering like this `d %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(length(unique(Sex)) == 2)`

Comment: @konvas this is `dplyr`, spreading and gathering is half the fun

Comment: @ilir haha fair enough :).. but if the OPs dataset is large, there is a significant speed improvement

Comment: Aye (+1 @konvas! even tho we're not supposed to do +1's in comments :-). I initially tried to do it all with just `tidyr` and completed the approach with `dplyr`. Much more compact & performant your way. And, kinda agree with @ilir that @hadley made it too easy & fun to slice & dice).

Comment: You should use dplyrs `n_distinct(Sex)` instead of `length(unique(Sex))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ave` to count the number of distinct genders for each name and only subset those those that have two genders. For example wiht the sample data

```
dd<-structure(list(Name = c("Anna", "Jamie", "Jamie", "Mike", "Sam", "Sam"), 
Sex = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M"), Total = c(10L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 3L)), 
.Names = c("Name", "Sex", "Total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

You can do

```
both<-with(dd, ave(Sex, Name, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))=="2"
dd[both, ]
```

to get

```
   Name Sex Total
2 Jamie   M     2
3 Jamie   F     7
5   Sam   F     6
6   Sam   M     3
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Joining a bit late, but here's a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .SD[length(unique(Sex)) == 2], by = Name]
##     Name Sex Total
## 1: Jamie   M     2
## 2: Jamie   F     7
## 3:   Sam   F     6
## 4:   Sam   M     3
```

Or, if you don't have duplicates, here's a faster solution

```
setDT(df)[ , .SD[.N == 2], by = Name]
```